# Unique wallpaper for desktop and lock screen

Tags: macbook-pro, desktop, customization, wallpaper, lockscreen

I recently got a macbook pro 2018 and was trying to change the wallpapers. I would like to be able to set a different wallpaper for my desktop and lockscreen. Googling around, I managed to change my lockscreen by modifying mojav.heic; however, that changes my desktop too.

How can I set different wallpapers?

Answer (score 1):

I found this blog post titled: [How to Change the Login Screen Background In macOS Sierra, Yosemite, and El Capitan](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29503/how-to-change-the-logon-background-in-os-x/) which illustrates a method where you first select the Change Background option by double tapping on the background.

[image: ss1]

After doing so go through and change your background to whatever image you'd like it to be. After doing this if you look through your system's `/Library/Caches` you should see a blurred version of your background as a `.png` file there.

For eg:

```
$ sudo find /Library/Caches/ |grep png
/Library/Caches//Desktop Pictures/0733888D-B1ED-4F99-B177-108EED834365/lockscreen.png
```

If you change this file out with another file that you'd like to use for your lockscreen you can then override the blurred version that macOS automatically generated for you when setting your background.

**NOTE:** Just be sure to keep the name of the file identical to what macOS placed in your `/Library/Caches` sub-directory.

#### References

- [How to Change the Login Screen Background In macOS Sierra, Yosemite, and El Capitan](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29503/how-to-change-the-logon-background-in-os-x/)

Comment: There is no image in /Library/Caches for me. I'm on Mojave 10.14.3 if that helps.

Comment: @jjayy - I'm on Mojave as well and I have that file there. I recently changed my Background to a image and that file showed up after doing this.